# Nested classes query and join

Tags: linq

I have the following situation, in this case I am looking flattening the nested objects and combine parent and child fields in a single row, instead of creating objects parent and child.

Also I want to combine v1 and v2. Any Advice?

```
public class Person
{
    public string idPerson;
    public string names;
    private List<Subject> subjects = new List<Subject>();
    private List<MedicalRecord> medicalRecords = new List<MedicalRecord>();
}

public class Subject
{
    public string subjectName;
    public string subjectId;
}

public class MedicalRecord
{
    public int recordId;
    public string doctorName;
    public string medicalCare;
}

void main()
{
    /// Assume that Person is filled.
    /// How can I join the two lists?

    List<Person> all = new List<Person>();
    var v1 = all.SelectMany(p => p.subjects, (child, parent) => new { child, parent });
    var v2 = all.SelectMany(p => p.medicalRecords, (child, parent) => new { child, parent }); /// here i want to select all fields instead of objects to avoid child and parent calling from below cycle.

    /// I want to join v1 and v2 and flatten the lists.
    foreach(var obj in v1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.child.subjectName + " "  + obj.parent.idPerson);
    }

    ///

}
```

Comment: So you want to end up with a flattened list of { Person, Subject, MedicalRecord }, however, a person has multiple subjects and medical records, so what is the grouping supposed to look like? What if there are more subjects than medical records, or vice versa? Are there alternative options available?

Comment: I would like to join and flatten al fields, of the two lists by Person ID

Comment: First of all, consider trying `var v2 = all.medicalRecords` since you want all the fields anyways. For joining them together, is there any particular reason you simply use linq's `join` with `on v1.idPerson equals v2.idPerson`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Person> all = new List<Person>();

    // Estract the flattened list of subjects
    var subjects = all.SelectMany(p => p.Subjects, (person, subject) => new { person.idPerson, person.names, subject});
    // Estract the flattened list of medical records
    var medicalRecords = all.SelectMany(p => p.MedicalRecords, (person, medicalRecord) => new { person.idPerson, person.names, medicalRecord});

    // Join the two lists and create a flattened object
    var flattenedList = 
        subjects.Join(medicalRecords,
                      s => s.idPerson,
                      m => m.idPerson,
                      (s, m) => new {
                          IdPerson = s.idPerson,
                          Names = s.names,
                          s.subject.SubjectId,
                          s.subject.SubjectName,
                          m.medicalRecord.RecordId,
                          m.medicalRecord.DoctorName,
                          m.medicalRecord.MedicalCare
                      })
                      .ToList();
}
```